# Oracle java stored procedure performance

Tags: java, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I am trying to create Java class in Oracle 11g drawing binary data passed as BLOB with awt graphics. The class loaded as a Java source

```
> create or replace and compile java source...
```

successfully. When I tried to run it I faced with terrible performace. It works but ~25 times slower than same code on my PC. When I tried to catch the bottleneck I got that all data convertation and math operations proceed in almost same time as local runned but the drawing procedures such as

`g.drawLine(x, y, x, y)`

have going much slower (up to 5 seconds per pixel).
I presume it can be fixed with setting right compiler options and recompiling class. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will be useful for someone.

In my case problem was solved by generating BufferedImage pixel by pixel with it's setRGB() method. I just needed to generate image of big matrix of float so it matched me so well. Performance is great.